# Redux-form fires an extra CHANGE action when deleting an element in complex fieldArray

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-form

I have a form built with reduxForm which has a nested fieldArray component.
In this component, I have two dropdowns. The first determines what will be in the second dropdown.

Here's my solution for that

```
// Set initial list values when hydrating form
  const setInitialQualifiantTypeList = () => {
    const list: (string | undefined)[] = []
    fields.forEach((qualifiant: any, index: number) => {
      const qualifiantType = fields.get(index).qualifiantType
      list.push(qualifiantType ? `B0${qualifiantType}` : undefined)
    })
    return list
  }

  let qualifiantTypeList = setInitialQualifiantTypeList()

// Change list parameter when changing the type
  const onChangeQualifiantType = (
    qualifiantType: string,
    qualifiant: string,
    name: string,
    index: number
  ) => {
    let newQualifiantTypeList = [...qualifiantTypeList]
    if (qualifiantType === '') {
      newQualifiantTypeList[index] = undefined
    } else {
      newQualifiantTypeList[index] = `B0${qualifiantType}`
      // setQualifiantTypeList(newQualifiantTypeList)
      qualifiantTypeList = newQualifiantTypeList
    }
// If it doesn't match previous type reset the value
    if (qualifiantType !== qualifiant.substring(0, 2)) {
      resetValue(`${name}[${index}].qualifiant`)
    }
  }
```

`qualifiantTypeList` gets passed as a prop to my dropdown component which gets the appropriate list.

However, when it comes to the fieldArray part, I lose some data if deleting any of my fields except the last. I've tried `fields.remove(index)` and even `change(form, field, newArray)` replacing the entire value, but redux-form fires an extra CHANGE no matter what, making my data go from

```
[
    {
        "qualifiantType": "94",
        "qualifiant": "1KBC-CA-Q"
    },
    {
        "qualifiantType": "95",
        "qualifiant": "2A"
    },
    {
        "qualifiantType": "96",
        "qualifiant": "3B"
    }
]
```

to

```
[
    {
        "qualifiantType": "94",
        "qualifiant": "1KBC-CA-Q"
    },
    {
        "qualifiantType": "96"
    }
]
```

[image: Form elements before deleting]
[image: Form elements after deleting]

The state I'm looking for does appear in the redux devtools, but an extra CHANGE action gets dispatched and clears it.
I've logged my `onChangeQualifiantType` function and it's not firing during this process, so that's not the cause.
[image: Redux devtools showing requested state]
[image: Redux devtools showing wrong state a couple actions later]

How I can I prevent this behavior so as to simply delete the array element and keep everything else?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, turns out it's because the sub-list is an async DB fetch, it  renders first with the new answer, the component clears it because it's a dropdown and the value is replaced by the time the data is in place.